# How to set option value in select2 type ahead search AND how to add an option group from ajax data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 to create a kind of meta search on several different types of data, I'm trying to figure out how to:

1. Set the value of the select option explicitly (I need to set it to a json string)
2. how to create an option group dynamically from the remote data

So I have the select2 call:

```
var meta_ajaxUrl = '[[~45]]?search_what=metaSearch';// modx url

$('#metasearch').select2({  
    placeholder: "Search for anything!",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
    url: meta_ajaxUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (term, page) {
      return {
        q2: term
      };
    },
    results: function (data, page) {
    console.log(data);
      return { results: data };
    }
  },
  formatResult: metaFormatResult,
});
```

and an example of one of the returned arrays from my php

```
$options = $this->modx->getCollectionGraph('FundRequest', '{ }', $criteria);

foreach($options as $option){
    $push = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'tipa', 'value' => $option->get('id')),
        'name' => $option->Client->get('first_name'),
        'program' => $option->Program->ProgramName->get('name'),
        'location' => $option->Program->Location->get('location'),
        'cams' => $option->get('cams'),
        'text' => $option->Program->ProgramName->get('name'),
    );
}

array_push($output, $push);


// these get serialized and returned
return $this->modx->toJSON($output);
```

When the output get serialized, it looks like:

```
{"id":{"type":"person","value":77},"name":"Foo Bar","cams":1234567,"text":"Foo Bar"}
```

So, when select2 the value  for the select control, it tries to use the id as the value attribute. If I look at the source I see things like:

Somehow I need to tell select2 that the value of id is '{"type":"person","value":77}' 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Also, the search searches for three different types of information, it would be nice to be able to sort them into option groups. Does anyone know how to dynamically insert an option group in the select2 results?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can adjust your `formatResult` function so that the `id` transforms itself to a json string. In my response I use an auxiliary function to test if the id is already a json string (which it will be after the first transform).

For the second question, you can use the `children` options (search for *Example Hierarchical Data* [in the docs](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)).

I have used static data, but it should work for ajax data as long as you provide a json object that matches the given example.

You can see a working demo in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w35gef8j/).

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="metasearch" style="width: 300px" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#metasearch").select2({
        data: [
        {
            text    : 'Persons', 
            children: [
            {
                "id": {"type":"person","value":77}, "name":"Foo Bar", "cams":1234567, "text":"Foo Bar"
            },
            {
                "id": {"type":"person","value":78}, "name":"Bar", "cams":3, "text":"Bar"
            },
            {
                "id": {"type":"person","value":79}, "name":"Yupi kay", "cams":127, "text":"Yupi kay"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            text    : 'Cars',
            children: [
            {
                "id": {"type":"car","value":1}, "name":"Super", "cams":1, "text":"Super"
            },
            {
                "id": {"type":"car","value":2}, "name":"Sport", "cams":2, "text":"Sport"
            },
            {
                "id": {"type":"car","value":3}, "name":"Exec", "cams":3, "text":"Exec"
            }
            ]
        }
        ],
        formatResult: function(result) {
            if ( ! isJsonString(result.id))
                result.id = JSON.stringify(result.id);

            return result.text;
        }
    });

    function isJsonString(str) {
        try {
            JSON.parse(str);
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
</script>
```